# Codeigniter 4 Named Prepared statements throws error Code 500: "The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement"

Tags: php, codeigniter, prepared-statement, codeigniter-4

I am using Codeigniter 4 and when using the "?" placeholder for the prepared statements, everything works perfectly fine. But I am preferring to use the named bindings as there are too many entry, but it throws out an error code 500:

> The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$pQuery = $db->prepare(static function ($db){
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_posts (content, author_id, display_image, video, posted_anonymously, foreign_image, foreign_title, foreign_url, foreign_description, date_created) VALUES (:content, :author_id, :display_image, :video, :posted_anonymously, :foreign_image, :foreign_title, :foreign_url, :foreign_description, :date_created)';
        return (new Query($db))->setQuery($sql);
});

$author_id = session()->get('my_id');
$date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$result = $pQuery->execute([":content" => $post['content'], ":author_id" => $author_id, ":display_image" => $post['display_image'], ":video" => $post['video'], ":posted_anonymously" => $post['posted_anonymously'], ":foreign_image" => $post['foreign_image'], ":foreign_title" => $post['foreign_title'], ":foreign_url" => $post['foreign_url'], ":foreign_description" => $post['foreign_description'], ":date_created" => $date_created]);
```

Comment: `:foreign_iamge` in your query should be `:foreign_image`

Comment: yes sorry in the actual querry it is the correct spelling, I just typed it here manually sorry. Still same problem

Comment: Please edit your question with the *actual* code you are running

Comment: it is the actual code that I am runnin but I just typed it manually here on stackoverflow instead of copy pasting it

Comment: Please *always* copy paste code rather than typing it in. Otherwise you waste people's time with typos that don't actually exist.

Comment: I already said that the code is exactly the same even if I copy pasted, but I still have the same error, I have already edited the code and copy pasted it, but still the same error

Comment: Is there any reason to use all that extra boilerplate when you could instead use a much simpler [named bindings query](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#named-bindings)?

Comment: to my understanding based on the documentation, the way to do prepared statements in CI4 is to use those extra boilerplate that I used as stated in the documentation just below the stuff that you linked. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#prepared-queries

I am fairly new to using prepared statements and also fairly new in using CI4 although I've used older versinos of Codeigniter before. I am just following the documentation, If what I am doing is wrong or there is a more efficient way, I would appreciate if someone could point it out to me

Comment: Looking closer at the documentation for [prepared queries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#prepared-queries), I don't think it supports named parameters since it expects the values to be passed in  positionally

Comment: yes that is what I thought as well @Phil, I already posted in CI forums but no answers yet :(

Comment: See [executing the query](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#executing-the-query)... _"The number of parameters you pass must match the number of placeholders in the query. They must also be passed in the same order as the placeholders appear in the original query"_. TL;DR you cannot use named parameters with the prepared query syntax

Comment: @Phil I think your findings merit for the answer proper. That way CI4 choose is so confusing and there is so little information around, that it seems a good answer is really needed.

Comment: @SeighthHellsing any chance you can use any other framework? I would advise either Symfony or Laravel

Comment: It's an existing website with lots of features and rebuilding it from scratch using another framework would be a huge and costly task, that might also take months of work. The most efficient and cost effective way is to use the existing framework.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** CI4's prepared statements only support positional placeholders. This is due to the way in which the [`execute()`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#executing-the-query) method accepts parameters; it expects a [variable-length argument list](https://www.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and not an associative array.

```php
use CodeIgniter\Database\Query;

$pQuery = $db->prepare(static function ($db) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_posts (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

    return (new Query($db))->setQuery($sql);
});

// The order of arguments must match the placeholder order
$result = $pQuery->execute(
    $post['content'],
    $author_id,
    $post['display_image'],
    $post['video'],
    $post['posted_anonymously'],
    $post['foreign_image'],
    $post['foreign_title'],
    $post['foreign_url'],
    $post['foreign_description'],
    $date_created
);
```

### A probably worse alternative

The API supports a much simpler query format with [named bindings](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#named-bindings) that relies on escaping values instead of binding them. However, unlike PDO named bindings, *each name in the query MUST be **surrounded** by colons*.

```php
$sql = 'INSERT ... VALUES (:content:, :author_id:, ...)';
$db->query($sql, [
    'content'   => $post['content'],
    'author_id' => $author_id,
    // etc
]);
```

#### Opinion time

This approach is sub-optimal and tries to scare its potential users away with some optimisation warnings that are surely premature.

Instead, take heed of the warnings from security professionals. From the OWASP SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet...

> #### [Defense Option 4: Escaping All User-Supplied Input](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-4-escaping-all-user-supplied-input)
>
> This technique should only be used as a last resort, when none of the above are feasible. Input validation is probably a better choice as this methodology is frail compared to other defenses and we cannot guarantee it will prevent all SQL Injection in all situations.

Comment: thank you @Phil, as I am new to using prepared statements, can you tell me if using the CI4 named bindings equates to the safety of using traditional prepared statements to prevent SQL injections?

Comment: @SeighthHellsing according to their docs it does. I tried looking through the source code but got bored after several levels of indirection. I wouldn't be surprised if they're using escaping instead of parameter binding which IMO is pretty stupid. I'm with YourCommonSense on this one; use something else if you can

Comment: _"surrounded by colons"_... there's a joke in there about the quality of the CI codebase, I'm sure

Comment: Thanks guys, I made it work, I used PDO prepared statements instead of the CI4 prepared query. I hope CI integrates named prepared statements in the future. Another question, which one is preferred, PDO prepared statements or MySQLi prepared statements?

Comment: @SeighthHellsing unless you have a very specific reason to use the MySQLi extension, I would always recommend PDO. The API is so much simpler

Comment: I agree, thank you @Philm btw I also posted an answer using PDO in case anybody encounters the same dilemma I had with using named prepared statemnts in ci4. Thanks again!

Comment: I would be so strict towards escaping. The solution in the other answer is using escaping (so is the PDO behavior by default) and all right. Though implementation in CI is questionable, but it isn't really following the the OWASP phrasing, "Escaping All User-Supplied Input" which is much, much worse, being horror of a sentence, which cannot be more wrong.